# c++ unset bitflag to its real value

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Hello is it somehow possible to set a bit flag to its real value?
example

```
int a = 0x01 << 7

a = 128
```

how can I convert the 128 back to 7 ?

I tryed `^= , &= ~, &=` 
but nothing I did worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you just have a single bit set then you can use a "count trailing zeroes" operation, e.g. using gcc or a gcc-compatible compiler:

```
int a = 128;
int bit = __builtin_ctz(a); // returns bit = 7
```